# Debian guest on VirtualBox with bridged adapter has no internet access

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtualbox, virtualization

I have setup a Debian guest and I am messing around with it to learn more about VirtualBox, Debian, and later after that is done I'll be messing around with a NodeJS server on it.

After a while I noticed I couldn't do some things with it when I had a Bridged adapter setup for the VM. NPM would not install packages because it timed out. I tried running "w3m google.com" and even looked up google.com's ip to check for a DNS issue.

No matter what, I cannot connect to any form of internet. But I can ping anything just fine. I can ping google, npmjs.org, etc.

Thanks for the assistance.

**Update:** I have been working on this more today, Newer router, asus, I read that people were having issues with belkin routers with bridged adapters so I switched, the asus is new anyways.

The host is connected via ethernet wire.
The VM shows up on the router just fine, And I connect to that device with the IP given by the router just fine. but I still cannot connect to google.com or anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to explain in a comment.  Below is how the bridged adapter works.

Yet, if you can ping from the guest debian that means some form of DHCP happened and you must have and IP (which is a different IP from the host machine).  I'd check router configuration to see if you're not allowing/disallowing specific MACs and/or IPs from the usage of TCP/UDP protocols (that is a measure some people use on their routers).

---

### Bridged adapter

A bridged adapter on VirtualBox simulates as if there was a bridge (well it is easier to think of this as a hub) on the cable connection to your (host) actual machine.  Even if the connection is over wireless the simulation is similar.

For (almost) all purposes the guest (debian) and the router the host machine is connected to are connected directly.  Have separate MAC, separate IP, they even give separate ARP requests.

```
router <---> host machine running VirtualBox
  ^
  |
  +-----> guest machine running Debian
```

This is done by sending packets with a different hardware address (you can configure the hardware address in the adapter).

You need to configure the guest system (Debian) to connect to the network as if it was a separate machine.  For example, if you use a WPA connection from the host machine you need to configure WPA (including the username and password) in the guest machine.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I'm aware of how the Bridged adapter works.
The pc host is wired, I've tried several things today, I will be updating the question to reflect what I have tried.

Comment: For now, i'm betting on a DNS issue (maybe caused by strange DHCP interaction).  Since you do not have internet repositories installing `dnsutils` might not be possible.  Instead a good way to check if DNS resolution is happening alright is a simple `wget -v google.com`, in normal conditions it shall first resolve DNS (over UDP) and then download a index.html (over TCP).  If you could give the output of that it would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but after some research I could solve a similar problem. I have a Mac hosting a Debian server. I used Bridged Adapter on interface en0 in my Mac.

1) My Mac is running on 192.168.10.101. I know that because I run the command:

```
ifconfig -a
```

and the interface en0 shows that IP

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 6c:40:08:98:72:4c 
    inet6 fe80::6e40:8ff:fe98:724c%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.10.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

2) Running netstat command at my Mac:

```
netstat -nr

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.10.1       UGSc          296      142     en0
```

I see that the Mac Gateway is on 192.168.10.1

3) Mac and Debian must be in the same segment as the Gateway, I mean 192.168.10.xxx. So I decided that my Debian must run on the static IP 192.168.10.115.

I edited /etc/network/interfaces file at my Debian server to look this way:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.10.115 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.10.1 
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.10.1
```

Then I did ping from my Mac and ping from my Debian and they answered Ok. I also have access to internet from Debian, because I have the same Default Gateway as my Mac.

```
root@debian64:/home/myuser# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         TEW-711BR       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

I hope it helps and if anybody have better explanations I would like to learn.